# I have Date Range I try to insert date range but it store 0000-00-00 how can i store from-date to-date in one data base column

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

This is right way to store like this

```
'bilty_date_range' => date('y-m-d',strtotime($bilty_date_range)),
```

This is Date picker function

```
$(function () {
         $('.select2').select2();
       //Date range picker
         $('#bilty_date_range').daterangepicker();
       });
```

I am Selecting date like this[image: Date picker]

I want to store date from-date to-date in one data base column

Comment: Are you receiving dates separately?

Comment: paste your `date range` code here

Comment: Please add any data that you get in your question

Comment: Only this much code I have

Comment: what result you get in back end ?

Comment: you submit form using `button` or `ajax`

Comment: whatever it's initially we need to find the where the problem occurs, it frontend or backend after that we able to help you ?

Comment: I get this backend result 11/07/2018 - 12/25/2018

Comment: are you using date format in sql table ?
if yes, please split the value based on - and upload the date in two separate fields or else change the datatype into string in db

Comment: first of all `using date field` you only store one date so its not possible two date in one `date field in sql`

Comment: How to store in mysql

Comment: just change the fields as string in database (not a optimise one). else split the value based on '-' and store the value in two different fields in mysql table.

Comment: Don't store two values in the same column. That will most likely come back and bite you. Every value should have their own column (of the "date" type)  or it won't be able to effectively index that field, sort on the "to" date (or even do a proper query on it). MySQL also stores the dates in the format: `YYYY-MM-DD` so you should also reformat the dates before they are stored.

Comment: Also, you can't run a string with two dates through the `date()`-function. You need to split the string into two two variables (one for each date) and handle those separately.

Comment: So how can i split string into two variables

Comment: My only thought is 'why?' - oh, the humanity